In Python how to assign variables from list that is sometimes missing data
My code reads data from NOAA's buoy service. The url is in .txt format which my code then uses to assign variables based on their position in the list. Typically the list which I have assigned the variable "lines" will contain the following info:
['Station CAMM2', "38° 34.4' N  76° 4.1' W", '', '3:00 pm EDT', '1900 GMT 05/22/24', 'Wind: SSW (210°), 9.9 kt', 'Gust: 15.0 kt', 'Pres: 29.96 falling', 'Air Temp: 82.8 °F', 'Water Temp: 68.5 °F', '']

I want to assign variables like this:
when = lines[3]
wind = lines[5]
gust = lines[6]
pressure = lines[7]
air_temp = lines[8]
water_temp = lines[9]

However, sometimes one or more of these elements is missing from text feed. For example, air_temp will be missing from the feed, so water_temp = lines[9] will result in out-of-index error. I know this is basic, but how can I assign variables from a list that doesn't always have the same number of elements?

You can for example use an if statement and the len() function to choose different code paths depending on the length of the list.

If something is missing, is it always the same thing? If not, how will you know which is missing so that variable need to be skipped?

Can you parse the feed with a csv.DictReader()? If not, how do you know which items are missing?

sometimes one or more of these elements is missing from text feed This implies that if an item is missing, you have no way of knowing which item it was.  i.e. maybe wind was missing, so gust should be lines[5], not lines[6]...

BTW, it's simpler to use tuple assignment: _, _, _, when, _, wind, gust, pressure, air_temp, water_temp, *rest = lines

Also, your sample data does have blank strings in a few places, so it looks like something added those blank strings as placeholders, to ensure the line would always have the same number of elements.

But what do you want to do with these variables once you have made the assignments? Specifically, what about water_temp? What if that is not available?

Most of the values have prefixes like Wind: and Gust: that say what they are. So you should be able to extract the prefix and use that to assign to the correct variables. Or you can convert the list to a dictionary that uses those prefixes are keys.

The feed updates 10 times/hour and different things can be missing until the next update. Wind, pressure, air temp and water temp are each occasionally missing from the feed, sometimes two or three things at the same time.

I use this code to display the buoy info on a PyPortal and most of the time even if something is missing everything displays fine with a blank line or two at the end. For example, if Pressure is missing, Air Temp will display where Pressure usually is, and Water Temp will display where Air Temp usually displays.

So if the input is raw text, where does the list of lines come from? Are you doing something like .read().splitlines()? If so, then the list is irrelevant; you should just parse the text. Beware the XY problem.

Yes, wjandrea, I parse the text using lines = html.split('\n')

A link to the data might be helpful - if possible. NOAA has an RSS feed for buoy data. Ex: https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/rss/ndbc_obs_search.php?lat=29.207N&lon=88.237W

https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/latest_obs/camm2.txt

Loop over the list and assign to the correct variable based on the contents of the element:
when = lines[3]
# initialize all the variables with default values
wind = gust = pressure = air_temp = water_temp = ''
for item in lines:
    if item.startswith('Wind:'):
        wind = item
    elif item.startswith('Gust:'):
        gust = item
    # and so on

You can also omit the initializations if you want to keep the missing values from the previous line. You should then do that initialization before processing the file.

How would you handle if, for example, 'Wind' is not in lines?

That's what the initialized variables are for. You assign default values that will be used if something isn't in the list.

You can store them in a dictionary using the string at the start of each element as the dictionary key.
dd = dict([t.split(': ') for t in lines[5:] if t != ''])

Output:
{'Wind': 'SSW (210°), 9.9 kt',
 'Gust': '15.0 kt',
 'Pres': '29.96 falling',
 'Air Temp': '82.8 °F',
 'Water Temp': '68.5 °F'}

Then you can reference each dictionary entry to get information.

data should be lines?
